# SlideShow - Botões com Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slideshow

Tenho que fazer um slide com botão de play/pause, *next* e *previous*. No slide eu preciso usar html, css, java script e meus botões precisam ser com jquery.
O botão de play/pause eu consegui criar. Porem estou tendo problemas em criar o *next* e *previous button*. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Term-Project / SlideShow</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="slideshow.css"/>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="library_slideshow.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        <h1>Beaches in Brazil</h1>
        <p><input type="button" id="next" value="Next">
        <input type="button" id="play_pause" value="Pause">
        <input type="button" id="prev"  value="Previous"></p>
        <p><img src="images/arembepe-sa.png" id="image" alt=""></p>
        <p><span id="caption">Beach in Arembepe - Bahia</span></p>
    </main>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS CODE:

```
body {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    width: 550px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 3px dashed green;
    padding: 1em;
}
h1 {
    color: green; margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 1em 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-style: italic;
}
h2 {
    text-align: center;
}
p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: .5em;
    text-align: center; 
}
ul {
    display: none;
}
#caption {
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

PRIMEIRO JAVASCRIPT:

```
"use strict";
$( document ).ready(function() {
    // create the slideshow object 
    var slideshow = createSlideshow();

    var slides = [
        {href:"barra-sa.jpg", title:"Farol da Barra - Salvador / Bahia"}, 
        {href:"guaruja-sp.jpg", title:"Guaruja - Sao Paulo"},
        {href:"jericoacoara-fo.jpg", title:"Jericoacoara - Fortaleza"},
        {href:"lencois-ma-.jpg", title:"Lencois Maranhenses - Maranhao"},
        {href:"pontanegra-na.jpg", title:"Ponta Negra - Natal"},  
        {href:"pontaverde-mc.jpg", title:"Ponta Verde - Maceio"},  
        {href:"portodegalinhas-pe.jpg", title:"Porto de Galinhas - Pernambuco"},
        {href:"rio-rj.jpg", title:"Cristo Redentor - Rio de Janeiro"}           
    ];

    $("#play_pause").click( slideshow.createToggleHandler() );  

    slideshow.loadImages(slides).startSlideShow( $("#image"), $("#caption") );


});
```

SEGUNDO JAVA SCRIPT:

```
"use strict";
var createSlideshow = function() {
    // private variables and functions
    var timer, play = true, speed = 2000;
    var nodes = { image: null, caption: null };
    var img = { cache: [], counter: 0 };


    var stopSlideShow = function() { clearInterval( timer ); };
    var displayNextImage = function() {
        img.counter = ++img.counter % img.cache.length;
        var image = img.cache[img.counter];
        nodes.image.attr("src", image.src);
        nodes.caption.text( image.title );
    };

    // public methods that have access to private variables and functions
    return {
        loadImages: function(slides) {
            var image;
            for ( var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++ ) {
                image = new Image();
                image.src = "images/" + slides[i].href;
                image.title = slides[i].title;
                img.cache.push( image );
            }
            return this;
        },
        startSlideShow: function() {
            if (arguments.length === 2) { 
                nodes.image = arguments[0]; 
                nodes.caption = arguments[1];
            }
            timer = setInterval(displayNextImage, speed);
            return this;
        },
        createToggleHandler: function() {
            var me = this;       // store 'this', which is the object literal 
            return function() {
                // 'this' is the clicked button; 'me' is the object literal 
                if ( play ) { stopSlideShow(); } else { me.startSlideShow(); }
                this.value = (play) ? "Play" : "Pause";
                play = ! play;   // toggle play flag
            };
        }

    };






    };
```

Alguem pode me ajudar?